# Switching 24V with 5V

Tags: power-supply

I have a camera system I am setting up on my truck.

What I need is a constant 24V when the indicators are on to tell the screen which camera to display.

I could use a pair of Hella 5HE996 152-14 timer relays, but they're out of my budget at $80 each.

So far I have a circuit that gives me a constant +5V while the indicators are on (thank you 555 timer and support components), but the screen needs 24V and getting the 5V to switch the 24V eludes me.

I dont know the actual current required, but being only a signal, I am assuming it is well under 500mA.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

*Edit: The only reason i considered that relay is that it was suggested by the camera supplier as it doesnt need any other components to work. I have already designed and tested the timer circuit to give me a constant trigger (blinking screen is no use to anyone), but its 5V, so I thought adding another transistor would be the economical choice as I already have 24v on the board, so why not do the whole job solid state.

Comment: You need a relay, which will not cost $80 (more like $5). You could also play with transistor circuits which may be a bit cheaper but a relay is pretty much plug-and-play solution that Just Works, whereas a transistor circuit will require more design effort.

Comment: Why are you looking at the Hella 5HE996 152-14.  This is a specialized time delay relay that, based on your question, is not appropriate for your application and quite expensive.  You need to be looking for a 5V SPST relay that can handle 24V and however many Amps your load takes.  If it's 0.5A or less as you say, then there are going to be 100s if not 1000s of choices.

Comment: Add a diagram of your 555 timer circuit. Are you using it to turn a modulating signal into a steady one? And by indicators, you mean turn signals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a relay with a 5V coil. Place a freewheel diode across it, most generic ones will do, such as 1N4148 or 1N400x.

Take 24V straight from the generator or from another available source. The current won't be an issue (just use reasonably thick wires). Placing a TVS on this 24V line is probably also a good idea. Depending on how well-designed the screen is, it may or may not be able to handle automotive spikes/surges internally. The camera/screen does need type approval for the use on vehicles, or otherwise mounting it on a truck (to be used while the the truck is moving in traffic) is illegal in most countries.

Comment: Don't forget that the 555 (and the 5V power supply) must be able to drive the relais coil. Otherwise another Transistor might be needed.

Comment: @kruemi I don't know what that 555 circuit is supposed to be and I'd rather not say anything about it, since it doesn't sound like something you could legally attach to a rear view camera or similar. This is very serious business - should one mount some home made electronics to a vehicle and those electronics are active while the vehicle is moving in traffic, one could be facing jail in case of an accident. A plain 555 timer IC duct taped to a truck together with some switch regulator sounds like an excellent candidate for all manner of EMI problems.

Comment: A plain relay however, is simple enough to reason about without going through EMC testing.

Comment: @Lundin  I think the OP is using a 555 to stretch the pulses from the indicator flasher circuit to create a constant 5v.  He then wants this to power the camera on the side of the vehicle that the indicators are flashing.  Which will then appear on the screen.

Comment: @HandyHowie Oh, hmm... well if it's a PWM then that won't work with a relay coil at all. You should then probably ditch the 555 in favour of some diff amp to get a reasonably analog voltage. Still the same concerns about EMC remain though.

Comment: @Lundin more like the output stays high as long as the input gets retriggered within T seconds. No pwm on the output and the input is a second or whatever the flasher circuit is on.

Comment: @Lundin I doubt PWM is involved anywhere. As I understood, the input of the 555 timer is taken from the left or right orange blinker light (turning signals) power lines, so he gets a steady 5V output when the blinker blinks (instead of an intermittent signal). It seems reasonable enough to me : using the light power inputs is very common (e.g. after market parking aid systems, after market trailer wiring harnesses, ...), and I can't imagine it would cause EMC problems.